# How to get background image name?

Tags: android

How can i find name of background image in my `button`?
I set `drawable`:

```
 ((TextView) findViewById(BUTTON_IDS[i])).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the views tag. Set the tag with the resource id:

```
findViewById(BUTTON_IDS[i]).setTag(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Then, you get it with `getTag()`, casting to `int`:

```
int background = (int) findViewById(BUTTON_IDS[i]).getTag();
// background will contain the value of R.drawable.ic_launcher
```

There's no need of casting the view to `TextView`, as `setTag()` and `getTag()` are methods of the basic `View` object.

---

Also, you can use `setBackgroundResource()` with just the resource id:

```
findViewById(BUTTON_IDS[i])).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Even for this there's no need of casting to `TextView`, as `setBackgroundResource()` is a method of the basic `View` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Initialize view 

ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewbyId(R.id.img);

//get the image name based on view object

String backgroundImageName = String.valueOf(img.getTag());
```